# Os Error Operation not supported in Databricks

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a dataframe and i am trying to convert it into excel sheet but i am getting an error -- Operation not found
Here is my dataset look like

```
    FILE                                     PATH                           COLUMNS                                            TYPE
0   board_fact_price    /dbfs/mnt/global/systems/board/board_fact_pric...   ['CODE_SalesOrg', 'CODE_UnitOfMeasure', 'CODE_...   Intput
0   board_fact_quantity /dbfs/mnt/global/systems/board/board_fact_quan...   ['Month', 'Article', 'Account', 'Version', 'Un...   Intput
0   board_fact_sat_quantity /dbfs/mnt/global/systems/board/board_fact_sat_...   ['Month', 'Article', 'Account', 'Version Inter...   Intput
0   DISTRIBUTOR_SALES   /dbfs/mnt/sgi/input/processed/DISTRIBUTOR_SALE...   ['YEAR', 'SEASON', 'DISTRIBUTOR_NAME', 'CUSTOM...   Intput
0   board_dim_version   /dbfs/mnt/global/systems/board/board_dim_versi...   ['SalesOrg', 'Version', 'CurrentVersion', 'Ver...   Intput
```

when i try to convert my dataframe into excel by writing

```
dataframe.to_excel("/dbfs/mnt/sgi/input/processing/campaign_tracking.xlsx")
```

I am getting an error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved now.

```
from shutil import copyfile
final = '/dbfs/mnt/sgi/input/processing/campaign_tracking.xlsx'
temp_file = '/tmp/campaign_tracking.xlsx'
dataframe.to_excel(temp_file)
copyfile(temp_file, final)
```